# $X \subseteq G$ is a left coset of $H$ in $G$ iff $X^{-1}$ is a right coset of $H$ in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, inverse

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. I need to show that for a subset $X$ of $G$, if we let $X^{-1}$ denote the set of elements inverse to elements of $X$ - i.e., that $X^{-1}=\{ x^{-1} | x \in X \}$ - then $X$ is a left coset of $H$ in $G$ iff $X^{-1}$ is a right coset of $H$ in $G$.

My attempt so far is this:

> $(\implies)$ Suppose $X$ is a left coset of $H$ in $G$. Then, $X = xH = \{ xy | y \in H\}$.
>
> Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, if $xy \in X$, $xyy^{-1} \in X$, since $xyy^{-1} = x(id) = x \in X$.

I know it's not a lot to go on, but that's pretty much all I have so far.

I don't really know where to go from there as far as making a right coset of the form $Hx^{-1}$ pop out.

And I have thought a little bit about the $(\Longleftarrow)$ direction and figure it must be very similar, but I'm sort of stuck on the same thing with it.

Could somebody please let me know where I should go from here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just consider that a left coset is of the form
$$
x H = \{ x h : h \in H \}.
$$
now what is $(x h)^{-1}$? And what is $\{ h^{-1} : h \in H \}$?

Comment: okay, I think I've got it now. For the $(\implies)$ part: Suppose $X$ is a left coset of $H$ in $G$. Then $X = xH = \{ xy | y \in H \}$. Now, $(xy)^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1} \in \left\{ y x^{-1} | y \in H \right\}$, since $H$ is a subgroup, and is thus closed under inverses.  Since $\left\{ yx^{-1} | y \in H \right\} = Hx^{-1} = X^{-1}$, $X^{-1}$ is a right coset of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: and then for the $(\Longleftarrow)$ part: Suppose$X^{-1}$ is a right coset of $H$ in $G$. Then $X^{-1} = Hx^{-1} = \{ yx^{-1} | y \in H \}$. Now, $(yx^{-1})^{-1} = (x^{-1})^{-1}y^{-1} = xy^{-1} \in \{xy | y \in H \}$, since $H$ is a subgroup, and is thus closed under inverse.  Since $\{xy | y \in H\} = xH = X$, then $X$ is a left coset of $H$ in $G$.  What do you think?

Comment: OK, thx! Just note that $H$ **coincides** indeed with the set of its inverses.

Comment: and it's that that allows us to deduce that the number of right cosets of $H$ in $G$ is equal to the number of left cosets of $H$ in $G$? (which is the next part of the problem). Anything more in particular that needs to be said about that? Like, do I need to prove that $H$ coincides with the set of its inverses, or is that just obvious?

Comment: please see my comment above.

Comment: You may want to note that the map $H \to H$ given by $h  \mapsto h^{-1}$ is a bijection, as it is its own inverse.

Comment: if I wanted to show that $\varphi: xH \mapsto Hx^{-1}$ was surjective, how would I do it? I started out by letting $z = hx^{-1}$ for some $h \in H$. Then, $z = hx^{-1} = (xh^{-1})^{-1}$, but then what? How do I show that there is an $xh \in xH$ such that $\varphi(xh) = z$?

Comment: I think after that, I'll probably be able to leave you alone...

Comment: Consider the sets $\mathcal{L} = \{ x H : x \in G \}$ and $\mathcal{R} = \{ H x : x \in G \}$. The maps $Z \mapsto Z^{-1} = \{ z^{-1} : z \in Z \}$ are maps $\mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{R}\to \mathcal{L}$ which are one the inverse of the other, thus bijections.